# What happens if no mime.types is included in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, mime-types

I have a custom `nginx.conf` file that I start nginx with using the cli, for example `nginx -c /my/path/nginx.conf`.

I have found that if I take the `include /my/path/mime.types` from the custom `nginx.conf` file, that the server still starts up fine, and webpages seem to load normally with no apparent errors.

I have been researching nginx directive priority, but I cannot see any reason that the [default](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/nginx.conf#L18) `mime.types` might be getting included. Is it safe to remove the custom `mime.types` include?

(I should clarify that there is nothing special about the contents of `/my/path/mime.types`. For the purposes of this question, consider it to be effectively the same as the contents of the default file.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did some tests and concluded that if you comment out the  mime.types line in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

```
# include /etc/nginx/mime.types
```

And restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

And you clear the browser cache before accessing again your page, you will notice that nginx will not take advantage of mime.types configuration (of course), and will NOT render correctly the media type of your content.

The following example, shows how styles.css is rendered (Content-Type: application/octet-stream) instead of text/css

[image: css file as application/octet-stream when mime.types is not active]

To sum up, yes mime.types is required for nginx to render the right media type of content.